# How can i solve my codeigniter batch update problem?

Tags: mysql, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

Hello guys I just want to ask in my project there are three tables product, color and product_color.I insert database using insert_batch then it work fine, when i update product_color table using update_batch then face some problems.Here's my sample code:

Database:

```
product:id,name,sku...
color:id,color_name
product_color:id,pro_id,color_id
```

Input Form:

```
<?php foreach($colors as $color): ?>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="color[]" value="<?php echo $color->color_id; ?>" <?php foreach ($productcolor as $key => $value){ $array[] = $value->color_id;} if(in_array($color->color_id,$array)) echo 'checked'; else '';  ?>>
 <label class="form-check-label">
<?php echo $color->color_name; ?>
</label>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Actually i want to pass primary id from product_color table.Here i pass color_id.Have any way to pass primary id from input form;
Here Is my Controller:

```
$colorBatch =  array();
foreach ($color as $colorvalue) {               
$colorBatch[] = array(
               'id'=>$id
               'pro_id'    =>$pid,
                'color_id'  => $colorvalue
                );
              }
$this->db->update_batch('product_color', $colorBatch,'pro_id');
```

Where $pid contains product_id;

Is it possible to pass product_color table primary id from input form or Have any better solution to solve this.Sorry for bad english.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code as your array structure is wrong;

```
$colorBatch =  array();
foreach ($color as $key => $colorvalue) {               
$colorBatch[$key] = array(
               'id'=>$id
               'pro_id'    =>$pid,
                'color_id'  => $colorvalue
                );
              }
$this->db->update_batch('product_color', $colorBatch,'pro_id');
```